# Ajax Form on load Event

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

Is it possible for a Drupal Ajax form to automatically fire a callback when a page is loaded?

I know this is possible using an external JS file and doing it through Drupal behaviors, however I would prefer to be able to do is straight from the Drupal form callback as this allows for less code and more security.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$form['mark'] = ['#markup' => '<div id="mytestid">REPLACE ME</div>'];
$form['test'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'My Title',
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::callback',
    'event' => 'load',
  ],
];
```

The `load` event doesn't work, which makes me think Drupal doesn't want to allow this type of functionality. When I use something like `click` or `mouseout` it does work. Is there some type of event here that I can use that will fire this ajax callback when the form loads? Or is it not possible this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [load](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event in jQuery doesn't work with elements without URL. This is not a Drupal issue. You can't use it this way.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there a way to do some type of page load event through the ajax form or am I going to need to do this through Drupal behaviors?

Comment: Drupal behaviors is the way to go since they are fired each time an Ajax call is made and on page load